# How do I get Android Studio to include resources in a .jar file?

Tags: jar, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 5. It still expects java plugins to be a .jar file built with JDK 1.6.

I had this working under Unity 4, but they changed something. Now I get this error while building the apk from Unity:

> OBSOLETE - Providing Android resources in Assets/Plugins/Android/res
>   is deprecated, please move your resources to an Android Library. See
>   "Building Plugins for Android" section of the Manual.

How do I get AS to put the resources into classes.jar? The "Building Plugins for Android" doesn't mention resources.

Additional information about my project:

The project references Google Play Services, so I need version.xml in there

```
<integer name="google_play_services_version">6587000</integer>
```

Which contains the version number for the reference in the Manifest.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

But if I include this file in res/values in my AS library project, it's still output as an xml file in res/values next to the classes.jar.

Incidentally, I'm digging the .jar file out of

`/ApplicationName/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/ProjectName/LibararyName/unspecified/classes.jar`

after building the project.

Comment: Have you tried using Resources folder instead? I think it will sent to res but you will have to nest an folder inside of it. I have never used res folder as when I am using Resources folder in Unity and make it into android Studio. It automatically put it in res folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, this is a warning and not an error.

Providing resources in Unity in Assets/Plugins/Android/res/ folder is not recommended, because it can cause resource conflicts.

When you provide resources in an Android library, they are correctly merged during build process.

Basically, you have three options:

- convert your plugin into an Android library. Or you can init an empty library, add your .jar file to bin/, your resources to res/ (there should be a manifest and android.library=true in project.properties). You can do this by calling android create lib-project ([more details](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#SettingUpLibraryProject))
- if you compile your plugin directly using gradle or in Android Studio, you can use .aar file produced, given that you have set your project up as a library (apply plugin: 'com.android.library' in your build.gradle file). Just put it in any folder of your project, it should automatically be detected as Android-only plugin.
- continue providing resources in res/ and wait for it to be completely unsupported by Unity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't try an .aar because Unity's documentation says it must be a .jar. I will try that.